# How to select custom attributes fields with relation in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, select, eloquent, relationship, eloquent-relationship

I have tables `emails` and `email_attachments` as follows:

```
Schema::create('emails', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('email')->nullable(false);
    $table->string('subject')->nullable(false);
    $table->text('body')->nullable(false);
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('email_attachments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('email_id')->nullable(false);
    $table->string('file_name')->nullable(false);
    $table->string('file_path')->nullable(false);

    $table->foreign('email_id')->references('id')->on('emails');
});
```

And my models classes `Email` and `EmailAttachment` as follows:

```
class Email extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['email', 'subject', 'body'];

    function attachments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EmailAttachment::class);
    }
}

class EmailAttachment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['email_id', 'file_name', 'file_path'];
    protected $appends = ['url'];

    function email()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Email::class);
    }

    public function getUrlAttribute()
    {
        return Storage::disk('public')->url($this->file_name);
    }
}
```

Doing this `return Email::with('attachments')->get();` I get everything as response:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "me@me.com",
    "subject": "My Subject",
    "body": "<html><body><h1>My test message.</h1></body></html>",
    "created_at": "2021-02-26T23:32:08.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-02-26T23:32:08.000000Z",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email_id": 1,
            "file_name": "foo.jpg",
            "file_path": "/home/user/laravel/storage/app/foo.jpg",
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/foo.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this `return Email::with('attachments:file_name')->get();` I get `attachments` as an empty array:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "me@me.com",
    "subject": "My Subject",
    "body": "<html><body><h1>My test message.</h1></body></html>",
    "created_at": "2021-02-26T23:32:08.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-02-26T23:32:08.000000Z",
    "attachments": []
}
```

How can I get only this?

```
{
    "email": "me@me.com",
    "subject": "My Subject",
    "body": "<html><body><h1>My test message.</h1></body></html>",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/foo.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I already did this tries:

1. `return Email::with('attachments:url')->get(['email', 'subject', 'body']);`

   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'url' in 'field list' (SQL: select `url` from `email_attachments` where `email_attachments`.`email_id` in (0))"
2. `return Email::with('attachments')->get(['email', 'subject', 'body', 'url']);`

   "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'url' in 'field list' (SQL: select `email`, `subject`, `body`, `url` from `emails`)"
3. `return Email::with('attachments:url')->get(['email', 'subject', 'body', 'url']);`

   "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'url' in 'field list' (SQL: select `email`, `subject`, `body`, `url` from `emails`)"

PS.: I'm using **Laravel 8.29.0**.

Comment: Try this: `return Email::select(["email", "subject", "body"])->with('attachments')->get()->map(function ($email) { return $email->attachments->map(function ($attachment) { return $attachment->url; }); });` or this `return Email::select(["email", "subject", "body"])->with('attachments')->get()->map(function ($email) { return $email->attachments()->map(function ($attachment) { return $attachment->url; }); });`

Comment: @Commander, didn't work.

Comment: `return Email::select(["email", "subject", "body"])->with('attachments')->get()->map(function ($email) { $attachments = $email->attachments->map(function ($attachment) { return $attachment->url; }); return collect($email)->put("attachments", $attachments); });` this?

Comment: Didn't work also, `attachments` comes empty. But maybe it's because of what @MKhalidJunaid said that `url` is a custom attribute and not physically present in my table.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can achieve this, usually, in other frameworks, these objects tend to be called "DTO objects" ( Data Transfer Objects )

For Laravel, you could simply get the resulting query from the database, and perform simple array transformations on it using the `collections()` API.

For example:

```
$collection = Email::with('attachments')->get();
$collection->map(function ($record) {
  return ['email' => $record->email, 'subject' => $record->subject, 'attachments' => $record->attachments ];
});
```

Now you would just return this as the response:

```
$response = $collection->map(...);
return response()->json($response, 200);
```

From your controller.

Though you should be aware that these transformations happen in **PHP** and not **SQL** side of things, but the user won't know which field you've returned from the database. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#select-statements

You can add `->select()` anywhere between the other queries and `->get()` because until that point you're still in the query builder mode ( You're making your SQL query )

So you could do this:

```
Email::with('attachments')->select('my_field','my_field2')->get();
```

Keep in mind that this works for **any query builder** methods. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries

Finally, you may look into API resources, as they provide a way you can format your responses. The documentation will explain it with far more better job then me: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources

Comment: your solution with map() didn't work, the `$collection` stays the same.

Comment: That's because `map` doesn't `mutate` your collection! It `return` a new value, that's how functions like that work :)

You have to assign the return value to a variable!
$collection= $collection->map(...)

Comment: So you can either assign the new value to the same variable or assign a new variable and use that in the further code.

Answer (score 0):

When loading specific fields in eager loading you should also select the identifier of the record which is used to map the related records. So in your case  email `(hasMany)` attachments via foreign key `email_id` which points to `Email`

[**See Eager Loading Specific Columns**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns)

> When using this feature, you should always include the id column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.

```
Email::with('attachments:email_id,file_name')->get();
```

Now this will give you 2 fields from attachments relation

```
"attachments": [
    {
        "email_id": 1,
        "file_name": "foo.jpg"
    }
]
```

So if you need `url` attribute which is a custom attribute and not physically present in your table you will need to trick the query builder to produce such SQL query with `url` attribute included, initially with null value and later on when this query output is transformed by laravel data transformation your `url`'s accessor `getUrlAttribute()` will fill this attribute with your expected output

```
Email::with(['attachments' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(['email_id', 'file_name', \DB::raw('null as url')]);
    }])->get();
```

Now attachments collection will have following data in it

```
"attachments": [
    {
        email_id": 1,
        "file_name": "foo.jpg",
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/foo.jpg"
    }
]
```

Comment: Hum I got it. So if I want to only return `url` I'll need to manipulate the returned array by myself, removing `email_id`, right? Another thing: Doing this how can I also filter the columns of `Email` table to only return `email`, `subject` and `body`? I tried `->get([`email`, `subject`, `body`])`, but it erased `attachments` array.

Comment: @ThiagoB.Bittencourt No that shouldn't be happening because doing `>get([email, subject, body])` it will give you these 3 fields along with the attachments collection, I just double checked on the local env

Comment: well it's happening to me. This works: `Email::with(['attachments' => function ($query) { $query->select(['email_id', 'file_name', DB::raw('null as url')]); }])->get();`. And this don't: `Email::with(['attachments' => function ($query) { $query->select(['email_id', 'file_name', DB::raw('null as url')]); }])->get(['email', 'subject', 'body']);`, this is erasing `attachments` array. Try to get the same Laravel version than me and same structure, maybe it's some bug, I don't know.

Comment: @ThiagoB.Bittencourt I tried it it return just return null.